# Manually submitng a form with specific submit pressed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with two submit buttons.

I want the user to be presented with a confirm window before deleting and if agreeing then submitting the form for deletion

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#delete").on('click', function (event){
            var form = $('form');
            event.preventDefault();                
            if(confirm("You cannot revert this action. Item will be deleted pemanently. Delete anyway?")){
                form.submit() //which button will it assume it was used?

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need a submit button to submit a form! by the way, why 2 submit buttons?

Comment: Show your relevant HTML code

Comment: _which button will it assume it was used?_ => None

Comment: @LShetty two buttons because one deletes and the other saves. It seems that it performs deletion though so it assumes that delete was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather that stopping form from submitting always, you can prevent form only after confirm alert.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#delete").on('click', function (event){
                var form = $('form');          
                if(!confirm("You cannot revert this action. Item will be deleted pemanently. Delete anyway?")){
                    event.preventDefault(); 

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: If it resolves your error, u can mark it as answer so that it can help others as well.